# Adding missing information to a table? (considering random start and end months)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table `spanishcourse`, representing the grades of students in a Spanish course. This is a school with courses starting every month, and students can start and leave the course randomly during the year (`month in` and `month out` columns respectively). The fact is some of these students were absent in some months, when they were absent the grade is 0. The problem is when the student was absent the column `month` does not show the grade as 0 (column `grades`).

```
month in    month out   month   student grades  
3           9           3       John    10  
3           9           5       John    8   
3           9           6       John    4   
3           9           7       John    3   
3           9           9       John    7   
2           7           2       Mary    9   
2           7           3       Mary    2   
2           7           6       Mary    6   
2           7           7       Mary    9   
1           3           1       Jane    8   
1           3           2       Jane    7   
1           3           3       Jane    5   
6           10          6       Rick    9   
6           10          8       Rick    1   
6           10          10      Rick    3
```

The output that I need is, now a small part of Rick:

```
month in    month out   month   student grades  
6           10          6       Rick    9   
6           10          7       Rick    0   
6           10          8       Rick    1   
6           10          9       Rick    0   
6           10          10      Rick    3
```

Conclusion: I only need to add the missing periods from the start until the end of a student. Considering Rick's example, we only added months 7 and 9 as having grade 0. Can some of you help me please?

PS: I already saw some other answered questions. They were the opposite because they considered as all data starting from 1 to n. They were not considering random months like this example.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `cross join` and `left outer join`.  The `cross join` generates all combinations between students and months.  The `left outer join` brings in the data for the matching records.  Records that don't match get a grade of `0`.

The following assumes that some student somewhere has a grade in each month:

```
select s.month_in, s.month_out, m.month, s.student,
       coalesce(sc.grades, 0) as grades
from (select distinct student, month_in, month_out from spanishcourse sc) s cross join
     (select distinct month from spanishcourse sc) m left outer join
     spanishcourse sc
     on sc.student = s.student and sc.month = m.month;
```

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d31dc/1)

```
select s.month_in, s.month_out, month, student, coalesce(grades, 0)
from
    spanishcourse sc
    right join
    (
        select distinct
            student, month_in, month_out,
            generate_series(month_in, month_out, 1) as month
        from spanishcourse
    ) s using (student, month)
order by student, month
```

Comment: By way of explanation of the above: The general principle here is "perform an outer join against `generate_series` over the whole date range".